# Reading from text file not working properly

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

Hey guys I am really struggling with a problem when trying to read a text file in android java.

```
public String readFromFile(String filename)
{
    String content = "";
    try
    {
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) + "/MyApplication");
        File file = new File(dir, filename);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        String line = "";

        while(scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            content += line + "\n";
        }
        scanner.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return content;
}
```

I tried extracting the content by using a scanner as well as a buffered reader

```
public List<String> readFromFile(String filename)
{
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    FileReader fileReader;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;

    try
    {
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) + "MyApplication");
        File file = new File(dir, filename);

        fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        while(line != null)
        {
            lines.add(line);
            bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lines;
}
```

But none of them seems to work. The functions return just zero, as if the file was empty. Also I get no error messages and I double checked the path. Usually those functions work perfectly fine for me, but I couldn't resolve this one.

I appreciate any help :)

EDIT: If found the problem. Everything is fine with the permissions or the location of the file, the problem was simply that I put

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)
```

in the code before I called the readFromFile() method. I think because of that the readFromFile() method returned that the file was empty. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Did you gave Permissions ?

Comment: Yeah at least the permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 1):

The second method doesn't work because in your while loop you are not assigning the result of `readLine` method to `line` variable. Change this

```
bufferedReader.readLine();
```

to this

```
line = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

Also, you are missing a `/` in a file path before MyApplication string.

I tried the first method and it read the file successfully. Check if the file exists, and check it's content. Also, check if your app has permission before reading by calling

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    Log.e(TAG, "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission not granted!");
}
```

Comment: As you said I checked for the files existance and its content. The file appears to be empty when checking for its length although it contains text. Also, I checked for the permission and it is granted. So I don't understand why it shows the file is empty.

Comment: @AlbertKlug Have you tried it on a different device if it behaves the same?

Answer (score 0):

did you give your app read file permission?

```
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" / >
```